# Python & Discord.py, if Server ID = 'ServerID' Leave

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So i have a Discord Bot that is written in Python & Discord.py, now my question is, is it possible to do something like that:

```
Server_ID = 'TheServerID' 
if ServerID = Server_ID:
    leave
```

Comment: What is `leave`?

Comment: @JohnGordon @Junes ```await guild.leave()``` https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.leave

Comment: @JohnGordon, just an example

Comment: Thanks @LuM, helped me a lot!

Comment: @LuM But how do i do that it leaves at a Certain Server ID/How do i make that it gets the Server ID and checks if its the same? Thanks.

Comment: Where in your bot would this go?  Is this a command or would it go inside an event callback?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the server id you have `ctx.guild.id` which is of type `int`, then you can compare it to any other int you want.

And if you want the bot to leave the serveur, you have to use `guild.leave()` which is a coroutine, so make sure to put `await`.

You code should looks like this:

```py
server_id = <the id you want to compare>
if ctx.guild.id == server_id:
    await ctx.guild.leave()
```

Make sure you put this code into an asynchronous function that would be maybe an event or a command.

If you have troubles to deal with discord.py, please refere to [the documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

Comment: And still thanks @NoeXWolf for answering, even if its not right

Comment: @TinNguyen thank you for your review, i slipped up a bit but i corrected now.

Comment: Thanks to both of you!

Comment: Im getting the Error that ctx is not defined, any fix for that?

Comment: you have to put the code in an event or a command function which provides the ctx as parameter

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way is to only check this *if you're joining a guild right now*, this is done with the `discord.on_guild_join(guild)` [Reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_guild_join). Then it's just checking the id and leaving if the id matches.

```py
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    bad_id = 12345
    if guild.id == bad_id:
        await guild.leave()
```